# Clicar na area do AutoCAD fora do Form (VBA)

Tags: vba

Preciso que a área gráfica do AutoCAD seja acessível quando estiver com um form ativo. Qual propriedade devo ativar, ou que código devo criar para que isso seja possível.

Comment: Lino altere a propriedade Show Modal para false

Comment: Opa Paulo, eu tentei usar este recurso, mas daí não consigo voltar para o Form mais. Ele fica como que desabilitado. Clico em um textBox, por exemplo, e após terminar o evento do click a janela automaticamente fica em "segundo plano".

Comment: Nem selecionando o form pela barra de tarefas? Testei aqui, não tenho o CAD, to usando Excel mesmo. Alterei a propriedade ShowModal para false, selecionei uma célula qualquer, quando tento voltar par ao form não volta, ai cliquei na parte superior do form, na barra de navegação. Funcionou. Vou procurar outra forma, vamos conversando...

Comment: "Nem selecionando o form pela barra de tarefas?" Na verdade o Form não aparece na barra de tarefas. Já tentei quase todas as opções de propriedades usando o "Visual Basic Editor" mas nada funcionou. Acredito que a saída será via código...